# How do i make efficient slots in an inventory?

Tags: lua, inventory, roblox

I'm making a game, and I've gotten to the point where an inventory is needed. I mean a custom one. I have the gui made and all the other stuff working, but I can't find an efficient way to make the slots(for tools) to slide up. It's like this.

Ok, so i have two items in my inventory. One at the very top, one directly below the first. I click the top one(to take it out) and the second one just stays there being awkward a little ways down from the very top.

```
--the only way i know of doing this is with a lot of if/elseif's

if not gui.Position == UDim2.new(0,13,0,123) then
gui2.Position = UDim2.new(0,13,0,123)
end
```

something like that,but what if i had 10 slots? 20? More if's is all i can think of. So, do you know a way to make this efficient?

So, according to the answer here, this would be the way to do it:

```
t = script.Parent
gui = script.Parent.Parent

t.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    t.Position = t.Position + UDim2.new(0,1,0,0)
    gui.w1.Position = t.Position + UDim2.new(0,0, 0, t.Size.Y.Offset)
    gui.w2.Position = gui.w1.Position + UDim2.new(0,0, 0, t.Size.Y.Offset)
    gui.w3.Position = gui.w2.Position + UDim2.new(0,0, 0, t.Size.Y.Offset)
    gui.w4.Position = gui.w3.Position + UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, t.Size.Y.Offset)
    gui.w5.Position = gui.w4.Position + UDim2.new(0, 0, 0,t.Size.Y.Offset)
end)
```

is this what you were meaning, or did i miss the point?

Comment: How do you "take away the top one"? Also, your underscore-based example doesn't seem to be translating well to text. Either that, or it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm sure you can come up with something better that that. why not implement for example 4 "displays" and tell each one of them which item to display? take pen and paper and make a sketch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, out of pure luck, I recognize your code as ROBLOX Lua. In the future when asking questions on this site, you should specify that you are coding in ROBLOX Lua, because the API is very unique and most people here don't know about ROBLOX.

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to make a GUI inventory slots, right? I'm also going to assume you are using a Frame as the GUI object, since you didn't specify.

My suggestion is to separate them based on their size. A UDim2 value has two pairs of numbers. The first number in each pair is called scale, and it's for positioning based on relative screen size. The second is called offset, and it's for positioning based on an amount of pixels. You should generally only use one or the other, which you are already doing, so that's good.

With that in mind, you can create a new slot that automatically positions itself beside another. Something like this:

```
newGui.Position = oldGui.Position + UDim2.new(0, oldGui.Size.XOffset, 0, 0)
```

Comment: he tagged his question with roblox. So I guess it was not just pure luck. :)
I don't know roblox but I don't see how this will solve his problem in any way. you just explained how to position something next to something else. if you remove the first item the second will still remain on its positon right?
I think his problem is more of conceptual nature.

Comment: How do i specify that I'm coding in RBX lua?